# How can i get mac id of a machine using PHP(the machines are not in LAN)?

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the MAC and the IP address of a connected client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php)

How can i get mac id of a machine using PHP? I want to find the IP and MAC ID for identifying the very unique user.I am talking about websites, not a LAN. I have a website for example www.test.com, and i want to know who all are seeing or login to my site, by getting there machine's MAC id and IP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. MAC addresses are Ethernet things, not Internet things. The machine might not even have any interfaces that use MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of HTTP, PHP can only get whatever information the browser chooses to send in its request. By default, no browser will ever send a MAC address to your server. The only way to get it would be with some sort of a client-side script, but I would expect that's beyond the capabilities of browser scripting.

Comment: can we use client script(javascript) to get the mac id and then can we send it to server script?

Comment: No, because there is no such thing as "the MAC id". MAC addresses are Ethernet things. The machine might not even have any Ethernet interfaces at all.