# No static IP but need to restrict access to a specific location

Tags: php, ip

I have a small web function that should run only when the user is in the office . But the problem is that our internet provider changes its IP regularly and i cant keep track of it. We have windows 7 systems in our office and they dont have any static IP. I cant even set a static IP as it will hamper the internet provider settings and will stop connecting to internet. Im stuck now. Is there a way with which i can make sure that a person is in office only when he is using that function?

Comment: Wouldn't your office still use an IP within a range?

Comment: Use a token that triggers a cookie to be written. If the cookie exists in the `$_COOKIE` superglobal, use your function then.

Comment: what about using a service like http://www.no-ip.com/ ?

Comment: is there a way i can get dns server address in php ? coz dns stays same i guess even if ip changes

Answer (score 1):

The surest way is to ID using MAC adresse since IP can be changed, MAC address is harder to spoof and does not change. It is the "serial number" of the network card. So unless they take the card home, they won't be able to access it. Have a read at 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php)

Comment: MAC address of the client is not available unless the server and client are on the same LAN segment.

Comment: Just a hint. MAC is easy to change. On my machine I have a field in card driver settings where I can put a new MAC. The same field I have in my router web interface. So, if users are smart enough - this could be a problem

Comment: @FAngel the computers in the office should not have the driver settings available to the normal users. So they can change the MAC at home but don't know to what.

Comment: @Salketer : i read the article and applied that code but i guess '$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;' this statement is not running as its not showing anything. How can i make sure that arp command runs on my server ?

Comment: The arp suggestion will only work if you are on the same LAN which does not seem to be your case. Scroll to Peter G Mac.'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dyndns to get the current ip.
Dynamic dns allows ypou to redirrect a host name to a dynamic ip.

So if you get a request from a unkown ip or more then x seconds have passed since the last request you can use gethostbyname to retrive the offic ip.

**Free Dynamic DNS:**

http://www.dnsdynamic.org/

**Getting the IP:**

```
$ip = gethostbyname('http://sample.dnsdynamic.org/');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to set up the server so it exposes 2 services - 'A' with the "special office-only function" available, and 'B' without.

Then, set up the network security so that Service A is only accessible over a VPN tunnel from your office.

--

An alternative approach might be to use PKI - get the office computers installed with certificates that are required to access the Service A functionality. However, while complicated, it is still possible for users with sufficient authority and knowledge to copy the certificate and install it at home.

Answer (score 0):

If your users aren't nerds, you can set a special cookie in the office computers, and check against that every time the user accesses the application.

(If your users know to to set and unset cookies, that would fail, as they would simply copy this behavior to their home).

Also, there should still be a specific **range** of IPs when connecting from the office (even if the IP changes), sample a few IPs and check for a recurring pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your office user with some kind of token, after they authorize. Then use the token to determine if access is granted or not.

The token can be stored in a cookie on the the office users computer, so authorization is done only once.

Comment: But then that user will go home, and use his token to authorize again, so what's the point?

Comment: authorization could only open for a short period, once everyone is authorized, new authorisations would not be accepted.

Comment: If the user is tech-savvy and has read access to their cookies on the work computer, they can copy the cookie and use it from home. So this is not a secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to office network - you may try to config your server, which gives an access to the internet, so it will add some token (cookie?) to all  requests (sent to your server). And you will check it in your code.