# MAC Id Getting From Client Side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the MAC and the IP address of a connected client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php)

Is that possible to get the `MAC` id of the client who is browsing my site..

is possible with `javascript` / `jquery` / `php` ?

I tried Using Javascript Which Is Below

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("MAC ID"));
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not portably, and not using pure javascript. (And php is only run on the server side, so not from php either).

If you're willing to use active-x controls, or maybe a java applet (i'm not sure about that one), you might be able to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

If by mac you mean the mac address of the network card, you can't.

php works on the server side, so it can't read information from the client, except what the browser sends.

Javascript (and related), only have access to a very restricted area of the system, which is the browser itself and the document rendered; you can include cookies there, but thecnically they are part of the page.

In the other hand, technologies like activex, in a restricted environment, like an intranet, can do it due to the inherent connection to the system, but only in Windows clients.

Bye