# How to block a user?

Tags: php, networking, ip

I want to create a php script which blocks a user and not a whole network(modem).
I know i can get the IP from the modem, but how can my server differentiate the user behind the modem?
Is there a possible solution?

Comment: There is no way just to block one user. You could block the combination of user agent and ip, but the user could change the browser. A hacker could cange his user agent as well so far almost not possible.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like 'Mac Address',
[Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php)

Comment: @Silent Except that the MAC address is typically not usable, as the answer you link to states.

Comment: Permanent, per-user block *are* possible, but you have to know how to hide a body.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way just to block one user: You could block the combination of user agent and IP address, but the user could change the browser. A hacker could change his user agent as well so far almost not possible.

Things you could try (but they may fail):

- Block the combination of User-Agent and IP
- Set a block cookie
- Set a block entry in the local storage
- Create a fingerprint based e.g. on the installed plugins or fonts

Comment: See for an example of fingerprinting https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Answer (score 1):

When user is clever enough to know how to clean cookies, it's not possible to do what you want without blocking IP.

Comment: There are more ways to track a user, but you are right that tracks can be errased.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is a clever ways like browser+ip, but the idea was that users can overcome all that.