# Php tracking[cookies]

Tags: php, cookies, cookiestore

I have a url shortener that I created to track incoming links. Currently the php sets a cookie and inserts visitor information into the database. It attaches an id to the redirect url and redirects the user to the website.

The website has javascript on the page that takes the id and tries to set a cookie on the front end. If cookies are disabled, the javascript attempts other things to store that id. The reason I am setting the id is due to the javascript sending random pieces of information to the backend.

Is there a way for php to have a fallback if the person doesn't have cookies enabled? I don't want to create a new database entry for someone who visits the same link multiple times who doesn't have cookies enabled. Don't want to be tracking the same person as 2 or more people.

**Edit**
If I can't prompt the user that their cookies are disabled, are there any alternatives?

**2nd Edit**
One of the comments brought this up, so I thought I'd post the link here: [User recognition without cookies or local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966812/user-recognition-without-cookies-or-local-storage/16120977#16120977)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if cookies are enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663859/check-if-cookies-are-enabled)

Comment: http is a stateless protocol

Comment: you've got 2 methods of tracking returning visitors: IP addresses and cookies. IPs are incredibly unreliable, and cookies can't be depended on either. In other words, tracking users on the web is "do the best job you can, but don't expect 100% accuracy"

Comment: I guess if I can't prompt the user that their cookies are disabled, then I guess the best job scenario comes to play ha

Comment: @Mark B, you are right - but we hear all the time in the media that websites is "tracking users" anyway.

Comment: And what if the user disabled JavaScript? The best answer I found on stackoverflow on this subject is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966812/user-recognition-without-cookies-or-local-storage/16120977#16120977). A must read.

Comment: ^^^ some people have to much free time :-)

Comment: @Dagon Says a user with 9K rep :-)