# how to timeout users from website?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, phpmyadmin

Do you use cookies or session to time out or lock out someone from your website if they have used it for 2 hours? I want it to lock and have them wait an hour before them using it again.

I got the idea from this website that had a message pop up and say

"you have used this site for 2 hours, please wait an hour and come back or become a member and get unlimited hours"

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

1. The simple one, in which you set a cookie or session (both use cookies in the end, so it hardly matters) to identify a user. The problem with this is that a user may simply discard his cookies or use a different browser, so this solution will only ever work for rather clueless users. It is probably *good enough* for your use case.
2. Go crazy with [fuzzy identification of users via neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120977/476), which may/would allow you to identify users pretty uniquely in a way that would not allow them to "change their identity" easily. This is a really complex solution though and may be overkill or unrealistic for your purposes.

Answer (score -2):

probably this will be helpful to you

```
  if( !isset($_SESSION['last_access']) || (time() - $_SESSION['last_access']) > 60 )
  $_SESSION['last_access'] = time();
```

This will update the session every 60s to ensure that the modification date is altered.

Comment: This answer doesn't really say anything. At least recite the major points you're trying to make here instead of just linking to another site.

Comment: @deceze hope this will say something

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the OP is asking.

Answer (score -2):

please visit below link to know more details with php code

http://riturajkumar12.blogspot.in/2014/04/expire-session-automatically-after.html