# How to get Chrome-Box Identifier?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

How can a chrome app. fetch a Chromebox identifier. I need a device identifier not a user identifier.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to get a device identifier from a Chrome app or extension.  Your best option may be to generate and store a device token (though obviously that will not persist if the user erases your app's data or wipes the device).  You may be able to use the example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23854032/1917097 as a starting point.

Comment: I used this option already. But surprisingly some machines chrome.storage and wiped on just a reboot.

Comment: I didn't want to use .sync too as it uses the gmail account not the device itself and I don't want users to be able to use the app on different devices.

do you know why would data be wiped on reboot only?

Comment: I have not encountered Chrome wiping `chrome.storage.local` on reboot for any of my devices, so I do not know what would cause that.  The only possibility that comes to mind is your app [exceeding the storage quota](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#temporary) if you store a lot of other data.

Comment: I only save a 5 char long string.