# Storage between two separate Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that should generate unique ID per browser. My current approach is to generate a random string and store it in `chrome.storage`. It works but when I disable the first extension and install the same extension under different extension ID, another browser ID is generated. I am looking for something like global storage for every extension to store the generated ID. Does such thing exist? Messaging between extensions is not possible because one extension is always off.

Comment: No such thing. You can set a cookie on a dummy domain or use a web server e.g. github gist API.

Comment: May be `chrome.identity` might be useful? Got this from another SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25852534/6016779