# How different two users with the same IP and user agent?

Tags: php, ip, user-agent

I want to limit a user to only place a certain number of orders.
We considered the ip in combination with user agent, but there is the possibility that two users to be in the same network with the same user agent. In this case there are 2 users and I identify as one. What criterion was also taken into account to make sure that there are 2 not one?

Comment: Require the user to register with an email address and login.

Comment: I want without user registration.

Comment: You could use a session cookie

Comment: Then I'll go ahead and close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966812/user-recognition-without-cookies-or-local-storage