# User database without registration

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I wish to customise Views to target different types of people.

How do I identify a user without a) any input from them or b) caching data on their device c) using cookies or storing anything on the device.

I want to save the person identifier in a database table called "likes", to which I'll log views, time spent viewing articles etc.

In the database without them having to register and on future refreshes, use that data in order to display content tailored for them.

I don't need it to be 100% accurate, and if people are going to make the effort to fool the system then I'm happy to let them, because I don't handle any sensitive data.

So knowing this, what are the key identifiers for users available to my website?

I envisage my site/service being loaded via Android/iOS app or mobile/desktop browser.

Once identified, I wish to save data about them for showing articles/content both now and in the future.

Comment: You could set a cookie on the user's device and use that to uniquely identify the user in future visits.

Comment: When I mentioned without caching data on the device, I meant without storing anything on the device, including cookies, I've edited the post.

Comment: Ask them to enter a unique token for themselves, (MSIE does not support keygen elements), otherwise there is no unique key to identify returning users. There is the session ID on the server side code, but it is not unique to the visitors IP address. Even if you use a client key generator like keygen or the encrypt api, you have to drop on the client machine either in a cookie or the DOM storage.

Comment: No, I don't want them entering anything. I don't need a single key to identify them, but use many. Meanwhile I have found what I was looking for in here, didn't google right before asking the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966812/user-recognition-without-cookies-or-local-storage