# How to recognize a previous user/spammer without cookies?

Tags: javascript, php

I am an admin on a chatting website and we get a lot of abusers everyday, disrupting regular chat flow. We keep banning their IPs and they keep changing them with IP-changer software and proxies. Additionally, they always enter using "Private Browsing Sessions" (this is our deduction, because cookie-marking them doesn't work).

**Is there any means to recognize their presence before they start their nefarious activities?**

We have javascript (no AJAX though) and PHP5 at our disposal. I have read in detail about "Browser Fingerprinting". It sounds promising, but it incorporates a lot of values obtained solely through AJAX (screen res, installed fonts etc).

I would like to stick to standard PHP5 as much as possible, and non-AJAX javascript may be employed if necessary.

userbase:

- 90% Windows-based

  - nearly 80% with windows 7 on portable devices
  - 10% on XP
  - 10% on windows 8
- 10% Mac OS.

Comment: As you are describing your problem, seems that you haven't introduced registrations in your website (may be not required by you). But Registration and Login is the first aid to address this issue.

Comment: What are you already doing to prevent this? Do you have to register as a user? Using an email address as the username? Is the email address blacklisted when they are banned? Do you have to pass a CAPTCHA challenge? ... blocking IP addresses and fingerprinting browsers is not very effective, as it is relatively easy to spoof them.

Comment: What do you mean by "no AJAX though"?

Comment: Capitalized proper nouns, deleted some extra words, and changed a few incorrect words.

Comment: www.desichat.org.  It is simply a "enter nickname and go" type chatroom. Considering that members should have the choice of a new nick each time, I know it can be implemented with login systems too, but it will make it much more complex and we will risk losing users due to an extra layer of complexity. So far we are running with chat control consoles and staying vigilant. It's barely keeping things running though.

Comment: have you considered captchas?

Comment: I formatted your question for some added readability, and a list. Lists are awesome. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should implement user registration if it isn't there already, with email address confirmation or oAuth validation. With pure PHP, as far as I can see, there is really very little else you can do. You can also try putting some data into localStorage (will require a little JS), not everyone knows about that yet so you might catch some low-swinging trolls that way. You can also make it so that people who don't have identifying cookies ('newbies') have to wait a while in order to join the chat. That way your established users won't suffer.

Must say, I'm really confused by your saying you don't have AJAX 'at your disposal'. What is AJAX except some JS that sends data to a PHP (or any other) script on the server? With AJAX you can auto-ban users as soon as they get, for example, five flags from other chatters. Without it you are really handicapped, because once the user starts the chat you have no other way of knowing who they are until they visit another page on your site, which with a chat application seems anyway less likely than usual.

Comment: Banning users based on flagging is a bad idea... don't give the bad guys more ways to f- with his website.

Comment: Well obviously only established users should have that privilege, and/or it can be done based on the percentage of currently active users flagging a particular user.

Comment: Ajax is not an option because the site already has a heavy hand with communication channels. Adding another one can affect members' chat experience.There are no "established" users, considering that no login system has been implemented on the chat. I guess there is still some hope with marking sober users with cookies (the bad guys would be using private sessions so they wont have any cookies) but it would still be a very slow process to mark an abuser and kick him out by member votes (not to mention, the hassle of implementing this system from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using $_SESSION variables to do the same thing as you were doing with cookies? I'm not at all good at banning people from a website but if it seemed to wrk with cookies, it should work with session.
[Check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: note that $_SESSION uses cookies, even if just for the session ID.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I believe that session is server-side and cookies is client-side unless i'm mistaken?

Comment: To _connect_ the server side session with a user you need a cookie or something else to identify the user. By default cookies are used.

Comment: By default it's cookies, and the only other option normally available (query string arguments) is even less suitable for the task at hand. So I don't see how this is supposed to help.

Comment: I agree with Mike. If using cookies, the abusers would come in as fresh each time so there would be no way to filter out the new good guys from prevalent bad guys. And if a new session is started each time the whole idea of session would be futile as everybody would be starting with fresh sessions and there would no means to identify the abusers.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, but could you check if this makes any sense? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082152/unique-id-for-a-device-with-php)