# Clients MAC Address

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for a solution for a php based web to get MAC address.I'm running appache server, the server is in the same network as the clients .Are there any  suggestions?

Comment: Isn't this what accounts are for?

Comment: Username/password? The mac can be easily faked.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that is secure (authentication), or just unobtrusive (convenient)? Do the IP addresses of machines on your local network change? Do they have network names? Cookies are a good way of seeing "ah that is the client I saw before" if security is not your main concern - and it works regardless of network location. MAC addresses can only be seen "this side of the nearest router" which makes it very narrowly applicable.

Comment: When you say client, do you mean a specific user (a person) or a specific device?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1420381/603003

Comment: Once wrote a blog article about this http://www.metashock.de/2010/07/reverse-arp-using-bash/

Answer (score 4):

The mac address can be configured, so it is not an identy. **Don't use network address information for authentication or identification, never.**

---

However, you may just use the mac address for informational - non security related reasons - in your application, so I will explain how to get it (on Linux).

First, the client's mac address isn't available in php globals like `REMOTE_ADDRESS` (the IP address of the client). You need to resolve it on your own using the `arp` command. `arp` can output the ARP table of the system and modify it. To resolve an IP to a mac address use:

```
arp -a IP
```

Back to PHP. We need to call the command above, passing the clients IP address to it:

```
$ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'];
// don't miss to use escapeshellarg(). Make it impossible to inject shell code
$mac = shell_exec('arp -a ' . escapeshellarg($ip));

// can be that the IP doesn't exist or the host isn't up (spoofed?)
// check if we found an address
if(empty($mac)) {
    die("No mac address for $ip not found");
}

// having it
echo "mac address for $ip: $mac";
```

Comment: The question asks about identification, not authentication.

Comment: Both topics are related. How will you authenticate someone without identifying him? But however, if you care about the difference, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may [ask for MAC adress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php), it can be tweaked; you can also ask for [client ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php) but it might change everytime.

Unless you're in a all controled LAN, just manage accounts authentication!

Even, if you are in a LAN, clients might get an static ip whch would be assigned by ... well ip so far. I think this may come up with OSI layers model stuffs