# run external command with php from linux

Tags: php, linux, window

`system()`, `exec()` etc command works fine in windows (Windows+XAMPP) but when trying in live server (linux) all functions returns `NULL`. How can run those function from linux?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
shell_exec("/path/to");
```

edit: 
   sometimes the problem is with escaping, wrap your arguments with
   [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: what is the path for `shell_exec('ipconfig/all');` this command?

Comment: ipconfig is for windows, linux is different world: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79000/what-is-the-equivalent-terminal-command-to-ipconfig-all

Comment: So how can i find MAC address for client computer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be related with incorrect path or permission settings on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this function in a php script to show the content of a folder:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('ls -lart 2>&1');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Notice this function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: `string(44) "sh: ipconfig/all: No such file or directory " ` showing this error

Comment: If you are on linux the command "ipconfig/all" doesn't work it is "ifconfig" instead ! You can do a man ifconfig for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting administrator may disabled some functions on the server for the security reason.

You may contact them

Comment: I have root access. How can I enable this function?

Comment: Go to php.ini configuration and search with keyword "disable_functions". You might see disable_functions=exec,system,passthru,.. Remove the required names from this.