# get ip and mac address of client using PHP or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I was trying to get IP and MAC address of client using PHP but I am unable to get that. I tried below code but it gives wrong MAC address -

```
ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
system(‘ipconfig /all’);
$mycom=ob_get_contents(); // Capture the output into a variable
ob_clean(); // Clean (erase) the output buffer
$findme = "Physical";
$pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme);
$mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+36),17); // Get Physical Address
```

Comment: @Archer to me it seems that OP is trying to get the _servers_ MAC addy (since he is issuing `ipconfig`), where do you see _client_?

Comment: @kayess My mistake, if it was one.  The mention of Javascript says client to me.  Does it not you?

Comment: @Archer OP is probably confused on the wording, might worth asking to correct it, however the code is PHP, so I assumed it might only be server side.

Comment: @kayess We've both made assumptions here.  OP, is this the server mac address or client mac address you want?

Comment: i want client mac address.

Comment: @mmthedependable then please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php).

Comment: Curiously, the code in the question appears to be from a (rather flawed) answer to one of the possible duplicates.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33537707/874188

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenters say on the question, you will not be able to get the client MAC since the PHP runs on the server, but you can get the client IP by checking `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or if the user is behind a proxy, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by many users its not possible to get user `MAC_ADDRESS`. To get user ip try this

```
function getUserIP()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```