# How can I get a client's mac address using php with linux server

Tags: php, linux, mac-address

I want to get a mac address from a client's computer which are using my web application.

I did `exec('netstat -ie');` but I can't get anything and I want to know the right way.

Comment: PHP is running on the server side, not the clients machine. Therefore you are not able to get the mac address of a machine that's on your site.
I think javascript isn't able to do this either.

Comment: `exec()` will fire on the host your website is hosted on!

Comment: This was already asked by the way: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following:

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$output = shell_exec($arp);
```

Keep in mind this only works with clients on the same ethernet segment

Comment: you're correct i'll edit

Comment: Hi Seitse , Can you let me know what do you mean by  clients on the same ethernet segment ?

Comment: Basicly i mean on the same LAN. Like ranges 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254

Comment: So this will not work for an external client, that IP won't exist in the ARP table

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$macAddr=false;

#run the external command, break output into lines
$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$lines=explode("\n", $arp);

#look for the output line describing our IP address
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
   if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
   {
       $macAddr=$cols[1];
   }
}
```

Comment: you need to execute the arp command first with `shell_exec()` before you receive output, so this won't work