# Getting mac(system physical address) address successfully in localhost but not in server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I wanted mac(system physical address) address of client and i got it but when i hosted in server am not getting anything.

The code i used for getting mac address is :

```
ob_start();  

system('ipconfig /all');  

$mycomsys=ob_get_contents();  

ob_clean();  

$find_mac = "LAN Card"; 

$pmac = strpos($mycomsys, $find_mac); 

$macaddress=substr($mycomsys,($pmac+49),17);  

echo $macaddress;
```

I dont known where am going wrong. Plesae help me to fix this.

Comment: php is executed BEFORE the html code is sent to the browser. In this case you are trying to get the mac address of the server.

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Comment: I am trying to get system physical of client

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the MAC and the IP address of a connected client in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

What system is running on your server? If it is not Windows, other systems (Linux etc.) don't understand the /all.
If it is Windows, beware that the server card need not be called "LAN Card".
First look at the full output of ifconfig.

Answer (score -1):

If you use windows server. Then try this code.

```
<?php
ob_start();  

system('ipconfig /all');  

$mycomsys=ob_get_contents();  

ob_clean();  

$find_mac = "Physical Address"; 

$pmac = strpos($mycomsys, $find_mac); 

$macaddress=substr($mycomsys,($pmac+35),17);  

echo $macaddress;
```

Comment: This gets the MAC address of the server, not of the client, which is what he requested.

Comment: So do you want get mac address of client?

Comment: If you want to get mac address of client, it is available only on intranet.

Comment: That is what is asked in the question - **I wanted mac(system physical address) address of client**

Comment: You can get mac address of intranet users. but can not get of internet users through router.

Comment: The client MAC address it not available to a server, this is because the source and destination MAC address in the packets header is changed at every hop, therefore the MAC is only significant to the local network segment.

Comment: i have used the same code and its working well and good in localhost but when i hosted on server its not getting

Comment: Sorry Ashok, but it is not possible to get the clients MAC address, purely because the information is not available within the packet that is received by the server, and the protocol that acquires it, Address Resolution Protocol, is only able to send the broadcast out on the local network segment

Comment: Yeah, its code only work on localhost, but it doesn`t work with users access thourgh router.

Comment: actually i wanted users to login only through there allocated systems only and inside some predefined premises (ex : like office only).How can i get this

Comment: You must try another method. On http protocol, it is impossible.

Comment: ok can anyone please suggest me how to do it like "actually i wanted users to login only through there allocated systems only and inside some predefined premises (ex : like office only).How can i get this"