# Find client's mac address with PHP

Tags: php, linux, macos, authentication, mac-address

I want to find the MAC address of my client, for my website based on PHP. Currently I am using the code provided to fetch the mac address on a linux OS. I want to know will this method work on any linux distro , and if not, then how can I fetch the MAC address for any OS. Also is there anything that works on any OS, wether linux or windows or mac.

```
$mac_linux = shell_exec('cat /sys/class/net/*/address');
$mac = trim($mac_linux); 
$data   = preg_split('/\s+/', $mac);
$mac1 = $data[0];
$mac2 = $data[1];
$mac3 = $data[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access your client's MAC address. The thing you are trying to do with the code above will get you your own machine's MAC address.
You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php) and find the detailed answer.

Comment: OK. Thank You. How do websites create log of users for any database changes without their mac? I wanted to store client's mac address everytime he/she updates his/her profile.

Comment: You can do it by saving their `IP address`. Usually this kind of logs are saved with a foreign key that references to the actioning account, action description and IP address.