# how to get mac address of device on live server using php

Tags: php

i want to get mac address of device of live server  but i am unable to get it on live server although it is coming on localhost.

```
$MAC=exec('getmac'); 
$MAC=strtok($MAC, ' '); 
echo "MAC address of client is: $MAC";
```

Comment: What error do you get? What have you done to debug? Does your live server allow `exec()`?

Comment: bro i am not getting any king of error nothing is displaying when i try it on live server.

Comment: **Nothing** is displaying? So your complete script doesn't run? Do you display errors? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)
What OS is your live server?

Comment: Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/hassanst/knowledgeinns.online/mac.php on line 4

Comment: And **that's** why you don't get output, you can't use `exec()` on your live server

Comment: then sir  what is solution for that?

Comment: take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Answer (score 0):

On a linux system the NIC card MAC address stored in file `/sys/class/net/<interface>/address`.

for example:

```
/sys/class/net/eth0/address
```

---

EDIT:

You won't get the client's MAC address from your server as you are serving on the internet.
If you're serving as an LAN network application, you can use `arp` command to query ip-mac mapping.