# Detect device id, mac address in Angular 7 and up

Tags: angular

Is there any way to get the device id, mac address, and things in angular 7 and up?
I have tried "ngx-device-detector" and it generates only which device type. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector

Comment: Getting MAC address in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Comment: thanks, but I need to know in Angular

Comment: Angular is just a framework. You can always use PHP codes. Also, I hope you know MAC address can be changed by user anytime they like nowadays. Getting MAC address is quite useless.